# Sprite Removed but Hitbox/rect remains

Tags: pygame

Hey all I'm relatively new to coding, only few months into my games development course, and I'm trying to figure it all out still, anyways I'm making a small bullet hell style space shooter for my course and I'm having issues with despawning my boss enemy. The players bullets collide with the sprite and the sprite is removed however the hitbox of the boss still remains intact and the player can keep shooting it to gain points.

```
      bulletGroup = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(boss, player.bulletGroup, False)
        count = len(bulletGroup) #Check if any colliding
        #Draw enemy
        if count > 0: # Begin Removal from sprite groups
            player.removeBulletGroup(bulletGroup)
            BaseClass.allSprites.remove(boss)
            #boss.kill()
            bossdead == True
            score += 100
```

bullet group is the players bullets

Images below show boss at top of screen and then the second shows sprite gone after player shoots but hitbox of boss remains

https://s15.postimg.org/e3a6hcf7v/boss.png

https://s10.postimg.org/jz8w4lfu1/bossdead.png

sorry still new to posting here let me know if you require additional code or so
thanks for any help

posting complete code, still new to coding though hope its okay xD
when posting this code in, some didnt go into code format so i had to adjust indents for classes and certain defines but should all be fine once pasted into visual studio or so after indent adjusted comments are whatever really some of this was took from previous work and haven't got around to removing/adjusting comments. thanks for any help

main py file

```
import pygame, sys, random
from Classes import *
from process import *
from process2 import *

############################### FUNCTIONS ##########################

def main():

############################### VARIABLES ##########################
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 30

BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)    

score = 0
playerwins = False
playerloses = False
playerdead = False
playerlives = 3
bossdead = False

timer = Timer()
countdown = 30.0
############################## Initalise ###########################

pygame.init()
size = (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
is_done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

############################# GENERATE WINDOW ######################


screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("YASS!")
player = Player(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT -50, 32, 32, "spaceship2.png", screen)
boss = Boss(285, SCREEN_HEIGHT -580, 32, 32, "boss2.png", screen)
#enemy = Enemy (0, 50, 32, 32, "drone.png" , screen)
yRow = 150
count = 0
enemies = []
for itr in range (0,50):
    x = random.randint(0, (SCREEN_WIDTH-32))
    enemies.append(Enemies(x, yRow, 32, 32, "drone2.png", screen))
    count+=1
    if count % 9 == 0:
        yRow += 32
timer.setStart(pygame.time.get_ticks())
############################ MAIN GAME LOOP ########################

while not is_done:

    ###################### EVENTS ######################

    process(player)
    process2(boss)
    #process3(enemies)


    ##################### LOGIC ########################

    BaseClass.allSprites.update() # CHANGE  2 - Calls update internally
    if len(enemies) == 0 and bossdead == True:
        is_done = True
        playerwins = True

    currTime = countdown - timer.getElapsed() # Format to 3 Dec. Places
    #Only use for Countdowns, since timers START at 0, this would be an unbreakable loop!
    if currTime <= 0.0:
        currTime = 0.0
        playerloses = True 
        is_done = True
    for enemy in enemies:
        # Delete Bullets that hit enemy
        bulletGroup = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy, player.bulletGroup, False)
        count = len(bulletGroup) #Check if any colliding
        #Draw enemy
        if count > 0: # Begin Removal from sprite groups
            player.removeBulletGroup(bulletGroup)
            enemies.remove(enemy)
            BaseClass.allSprites.remove(enemy)
            score += 1

        bulletGroup = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(boss, player.bulletGroup, False)
        count = len(bulletGroup) #Check if any colliding
        #Draw enemy
        if count > 0: # Begin Removal from sprite groups
            player.removeBulletGroup(bulletGroup)
            BaseClass.allSprites.remove(boss)
            #boss.kill()
            bossdead = True
            score += 100

        bulletGroup2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy.bulletGroup2, False)
        count = len(bulletGroup2) #Check if any colliding
        #Draw enemy
        if count > 0: # Begin Removal from sprite groups
            enemy.removeBulletGroup2(bulletGroup2)
            #player = None
            BaseClass.allSprites.remove(player)
            playerdead = True
            tempX = player.rect.x
            tempY = player.rect.y

            player = Player(tempX, tempY, 32, 32, "boom2.png", screen)
            is_done = True

        bulletGroup3 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, boss.bulletGroup3, False)
        count = len(bulletGroup3) #Check if any colliding
        #Draw enemy
        if count > 0: # Begin Removal from sprite groups
            boss.removeBulletGroup3(bulletGroup3)
            #player = None
            BaseClass.allSprites.remove(player)
            playerdead = True
            tempX = player.rect.x
            tempY = player.rect.y

            player = Player(tempX, tempY, 32, 32, "boom2.png", screen)
            is_done = True

    ##################### DRAWING CODE GOES HERE #########################

    screen.fill(BLACK) # CHANGE 3  Change background to white instead of black


    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,50))
    drawText(screen, "arial", 24 , WHITE, BLACK, 50, 10, "Bullets: " + str(player.bulletClip))
    drawText(screen, "arial", 24 , WHITE, BLACK, 250, 10, "Score: " + str(score))
    drawText(screen, "arial", 24 , WHITE, BLACK, 450, 10, "Time: " + str('%.3f'%currTime))
    BaseClass.allSprites.draw(screen)
    ##################### CLEAR SCREEN AND SET FPS #######################
    if playerwins == True and is_done == True:
        #name = input("Enter Name: ") #Take input to personally congratulate the winner
        drawText(screen, "arial", 28, GREEN, BLACK, SCREEN_WIDTH/2-100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, "You Win!")
        drawText(screen, "arial", 28, GREEN, BLACK, SCREEN_WIDTH/2-100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2+40, "Score: " +str(score))
        drawText(screen, "arial", 28, GREEN, BLACK, SCREEN_WIDTH/2-100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2+80, "Time Left: " +str(currTime))

    if playerloses == True:
        drawText(screen, "arial", 28, GREEN, BLACK, SCREEN_WIDTH/2-100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, "You Lose!")
        drawText(screen, "arial", 28, GREEN, BLACK, SCREEN_WIDTH/2-100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2+40, "Score: " +str(score))
        drawText(screen, "arial", 28, GREEN, BLACK, SCREEN_WIDTH/2-100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2+80, "You Ran Out of Time!")

    if playerdead == True:
        drawText(screen, "arial", 28, GREEN, BLACK, SCREEN_WIDTH/2-100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, "You Lose!")
        drawText(screen, "arial", 28, GREEN, BLACK, SCREEN_WIDTH/2-100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2+40, "Score: " +str(score))
        drawText(screen, "arial", 28, GREEN, BLACK, SCREEN_WIDTH/2-100, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2+80, "You Died =(")

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
    #End Game Loop
    #################### QUIT PROGRAM #############################
pygame.time.wait(3000)
pygame.quit() # exits pygame window
sys.exit() # exits cmd line

main()
```

classes py file

```
import pygame, sys, random
from process import Timer

class BaseClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):                  # Calls the Sprite    Class init function

allSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()      # A group (think list) which will contain every sprite in the game

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string):

    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) # Call Parent Constructor Image
    BaseClass.allSprites.add(self)      # Adds the image to the allsprites group

    self.image = pygame.image.load(image_string)

    # Size and placement
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height

    # Change 4 - Motion - Added Motion to Base Class
    # Change 5 - Set Default Velocity to 0
    self.velx = 0
    self.vely = 0

    self.allSprites.add(self) # Adds sprite to the allsprites group

class Player(BaseClass): # Inherits from BaseClass

bulletGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string, screen):
    BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string)
    self.bulletClip = 50
    self.screen_ref = screen 
    #self.velx = 3
    #self.vely = 3     
    #self.collideRect = pygame.rect.Rect((0,0) , (-100, 1))
    #self.collideRect.midbottom = self.rect.midbottom      

def checkScreenBounds(self):
    screen_W = self.screen_ref.get_width() - self.width
    screen_H = self.screen_ref.get_height() - self.height
    if self.rect.x < 0:
        self.rect.x = 0
    elif self.rect.x > screen_W-13:
        self.rect.x = screen_W-13
    if self.rect.y < 0:
        self.rect.y = 0
    elif self.rect.y > screen_H-15:
        self.rect.y = screen_H-15

def update(self):
    self.rect.x += self.velx # we only want x movement
    self.rect.y += self.vely
    self.checkScreenBounds()
    sprites = self.bulletGroup.sprites()
    for sprite in sprites:
        if sprite.hit == True:
            self.bulletGroup.remove(sprite)
            BaseClass.remove(sprite)
            self.bulletClip += 1

def fire(self):
    #Set to player postion
    if self.bulletClip > 1:
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.x,self.rect.y+20, 16, 16, "laserBig.png", self.screen_ref)
        bullet2 = Bullet(self.rect.x+40,self.rect.y+20, 16, 16, "laserBig.png", self.screen_ref)
        bullet.speed = -8 # we want it to move up so -y in screen co-ords
        bullet2.speed = -8
        self.bulletGroup.add(bullet)
        self.bulletGroup.add(bullet2)
        self.bulletClip -= 2

def removeBulletGroup(self, group):
    count = len(group)
    self.bulletGroup.remove(group)
    BaseClass.allSprites.remove(group)
    self.bulletClip += count


class Bullet(BaseClass): # inherits from BaseClass

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string, screen): # Constructor
    BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string)
    self.screen_ref = screen
    self.hit = False
    self.speed = 0
#check on y axis for boundaries
def checkScreenBounds(self):
    screen_H = self.screen_ref.get_height() - self.height
    if self.rect.y < 50 or self.rect.y > screen_H:
        self.hit = True

def update(self):
    self.rect.y += self.speed # we only want Y movement
    self.checkScreenBounds()

class Enemies(BaseClass):

bulletGroup2 = pygame.sprite.Group()

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string, screen,):
    BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string)
    self.bulletClip2 = 2000

    self.screen_ref = screen
    #Abosulute Respawn start if required
    self.startX = x
    self.startY = y
    # Select Speed of 5 to 10 pixels per frame
    self.velx = random.randint(5,10)
    # Select Left or Right
    dir_choice = random.randint(0,1)
    if dir_choice == 0:
        self.velx *= -1
    self.countdown = random.randint(30,40)
    self.timeInc = self.countdown
    self.timer = Timer()
    self.timer.setStart(pygame.time.get_ticks())

def checkScreenBounds(self):
    screen_W = self.screen_ref.get_width() - self.width
    if self.rect.x < 0:
        self.velx *= -1
    elif self.rect.x > screen_W :
        self.velx *= -1

def update(self):
    self.rect.x += self.velx # We only want X movement
    self.checkScreenBounds()
    sprites = self.bulletGroup2.sprites()
    for sprite in sprites:
        if sprite.hit == True:
            self.bulletGroup2.remove(sprite)
            BaseClass.remove(sprite)
            self.bulletClip2 += 1
    currTime = self.countdown - self.timer.getElapsed() # Format to 3 Dec. Places
    if currTime <= 0:
        self.countdown = self.timer.getElapsed() + self.timeInc
        self.fire()

def fire(self):
    #Set to player postion
    if self.bulletClip2 > 1:
        enemybullet = EnemyBullet(self.rect.x,self.rect.y+20, 16, 16, "enemy bullet1.png", self.screen_ref)
        enemybullet.speed = 4 # we want it to move up so -y in screen co-ords
        self.bulletGroup2.add(enemybullet)
        self.bulletClip2 -= 2


def removeBulletGroup2(self, group):
    count = len(group)
    self.bulletGroup2.remove(group)
    BaseClass.allSprites.remove(group)
    self.bulletClip2 += count

class EnemyBullet(BaseClass): # inherits from BaseClass

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string, screen): # Constructor
    BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string)
    self.screen_ref = screen
    self.hit = False
    self.speed = 0
#check on y axis for boundaries
def checkScreenBounds(self):
    screen_H = self.screen_ref.get_height() - self.height
    if self.rect.y < 50 or self.rect.y > screen_H:
        self.hit = True

def update(self):
    self.rect.y += self.speed # we only want Y movement
    self.checkScreenBounds()


class Boss(BaseClass): # Inherits from BaseClass

bulletGroup3 = pygame.sprite.Group()

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string, screen):
    BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string)
    self.bulletClip3 = 25
    self.screen_ref = screen 
    #self.velx = 3
    #self.vely = 3  
    self.velx = random.randint(5,10)
    dir_choice = random.randint(0,1)
    if dir_choice == 0:
        self.velx *= -1
    self.countdown = random.randint(2,3)
    self.timeInc = self.countdown
    self.timer = Timer()
    self.timer.setStart(pygame.time.get_ticks())         

def checkScreenBounds(self):
    screen_W = self.screen_ref.get_width() - self.width
    if self.rect.x < 5:
        self.velx *= -1
    elif self.rect.x > screen_W-45 :
        self.velx *= -1

def update(self):
    self.rect.x += self.velx # we only want x movement
    self.rect.y += self.vely
    self.checkScreenBounds()
    sprites = self.bulletGroup3.sprites()

    for sprite in sprites:
        if sprite.hit == True:
            self.bulletGroup3.remove(sprite)
            BaseClass.remove(sprite)
            self.bulletClip3 += 1
    currTime = self.countdown - self.timer.getElapsed() # Format to 3 Dec. Places
    if currTime <= 0:
        self.countdown = self.timer.getElapsed() + self.timeInc
        self.fire()

def fire(self):
    #Set to player postion
    if self.bulletClip3 > 1:
        bossbullet = BossBullet(self.rect.x+13,self.rect.y+90, 16, 16, "boss bullet2.png", self.screen_ref)
        #bossbullet2 = BossBullet(self.rect.x+110,self.rect.y+120, 16, 16, "boss bullet.png", self.screen_ref)
        bossbullet.speed = 8 # we want it to move up so -y in screen co-ords
       # bossbullet2.speed = 5
        self.bulletGroup3.add(bossbullet)
        #self.bulletGroup3.add(bossbullet2)
        self.bulletClip3 -= 2

def removeBulletGroup3(self, group):
    count = len(group)
    self.bulletGroup3.remove(group)
    BaseClass.allSprites.remove(group)
    self.bulletClip3 += count

class BossBullet(BaseClass): # inherits from BaseClass

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string, screen): # Constructor
    BaseClass.__init__(self, x, y, width, height, image_string)
    self.screen_ref = screen
    self.hit = False
    self.speed = 0
#check on y axis for boundaries
def checkScreenBounds(self):
    screen_H = self.screen_ref.get_height() - self.height
    if self.rect.y < 50 or self.rect.y > screen_H:
        self.hit = True

def update(self):
    self.rect.y += self.speed # we only want Y movement
    self.checkScreenBounds()
```

process py file

```
import pygame, sys

def process(player):
# GLOBAL EVENTS LOOP
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        is_done = True
        sys.exit()
# GLOBAL KEY INPUT
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    player.fire()
if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
    is_done = True 
    sys.exit()
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    player.velx = 12
elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
    player.velx = -12
else:
    player.velx = 0
if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    player.vely = 4
elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
    player.vely = -4
else:
    player.vely = 0

def drawText(screen, fontname, size, forecolour, backcolour, x, y, text):
# Display some text
font = pygame.font.SysFont(fontname,size)
text = font.render(text, True, forecolour, backcolour)
textpos = text.get_rect()
textpos.x = x
textpos.y = y
screen.blit(text, textpos)

class Timer():
def __init__(self):
    self.start_ticks = 0

def setStart(self, val):
    self.start_ticks = val

def getElapsed(self):
    seconds = (pygame.time.get_ticks()- self.start_ticks) / 1000
    return seconds
```

Comment: `bossdead == True` should be `bossdead = True`, right?

Comment: yes it should just changed it before in testing

Comment: Yes, we need more code. Post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: added complete code

Comment: Thanks for the update, but you can hardly call that a "minimal" example. ;) Also, the `process2` function is missing, and next time replace the images with `pygame.Surface`s. It'll take quite a lot of time to go through so much code. One thing you should change already is the image loading in the classes. Every time you create an instance the image has to be loaded again. Load images once at the beginning of the game and then reuse them.

Comment: haha sorry, ye thats the way i was taught to do the images,and process 2 was a testing thing and isnt used no more it's all good i can ask my lecturer when back in class next week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are removing the sprite with

```
BaseClass.allSprites.remove(boss)
```

but you aren't actually removing the boss. So it won't draw it in your "draw all sprites" function, but the next time it goes through the game loop, it is still checking collision with the boss. You could always block the collision detection code with the bossdead variable:

```
if not bossdead    
    bulletGroup = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(boss, player.bulletGroup, False)
    count = len(bulletGroup) #Check if any colliding
    #Draw enemy
    if count > 0: # Begin Removal from sprite groups
        player.removeBulletGroup(bulletGroup)
        BaseClass.allSprites.remove(boss)
        #boss.kill()
        bossdead = True
        score += 100
```